# Were firearms ever used in the Dragonriders of Pern series?

Tags: anne-mccaffrey, pern

Having read the books some time ago, I am under the impression that firearms are never used or mentioned in the *Dragonriders of Pern* series.

In support of this idea, the villains in *Dragon's Dawn* do not seem to have them handy, nor are they mentioned as being used against hostile creatures that would have been convenient to have them available for.

I imagine that firearms would have been among the technologies left behind as per the colony charter, but there were other technologies that were used briefly during the start-up phase after landing.

Do I remember correctly, or was there mention of firearms somewhere in the books?

Comment: While they do bring guns on the colony ships, they don't last very long without the machinery required to maintain them and manufacture new parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There certainly aren't any firearms in the main timeline (Dragonflight and onwards) or in the secondary one (Moreta's Ride and Nerilka's Story), but there *are* faint references to them in the post-Landing timeline. I searched *Dragon's Dawn* and *First Fall* for "guns", "firearms" and the like, but could find only this passage:

> Leaving Sorka to help the Tubbermans assemble their gear, Sean and the others, armed with **the pistols**, cautiously approached the wrecked compound.

*(Dragon's Dawn, about 85% of the way in, emphasis mine)*

Even this, I think, was a very rare and unusual occasion, when the dragonriders are approaching an unknown and potentially dangerous *human* situation (rather than a Thread or ecological situation), so I'm guessing they dug out the never-used pistols from a dusty drawer.

Comment: I suppose it makes sense that there were some around, as many of the colonists were ex-military. I wonder why Bitra and that lot did not did not seem to have any to use. Locked up in an arms locker or something perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember any firearms on Pern either and I've read pretty much any McCaffrey book that I could get my hands on. There is a list of possible weapons on Pern at [Arolos Weyr](http://www.arolosweyr.co.uk/arolos.php?p=articles/display_article.php&id=164).

Wikipedia says that Pern is "a feudal society at a **medieval to Renaissance level of technology**." I guess this makes it feasible for guns/pistols to arise, given that the Chinese discovered gunpowder in the 1200s and matchlock guns, wheel lock guns and flintlock guns were created in the 1400s, 1500s and 1600s respectively. I can't remember if the Pernese have discovered gunpowder... Perhaps for mining?

Comment: In _All The Weyrs Of Pern_ Fandarel knows of black powder and nitro (he is trying to understand the explosive power of antimatter).  Undoubtedly used for mining (and perhaps for clearing tree stumps from fields).